# Editing entries of QTreeView with QFileSystemModel

Tags: python, pyqt5, qtreeview

I have written a program to en/decyrpt files and folders (**including** the names of them). The encrypted folder looks like that:

```
- rootFolder:        folder
    - 19479:         folder
          91039      file
          49761      file
    - 06937:         folder
```

Next, I wanted to make a *TreeView* to represent the folder structure with the decrypted names (so you know which is which). The problem here is that I can't access the items of the TreeView/TreeModel. My goal is to

1. read out every single entry (e.g with a for loop)
2. (*optional: get absolute path of entry if possible*)
3. update the entries with the decrypted ones

My current code:

```py
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QDialog, QTreeView
from PyQt5.Qt import QFileSystemModel
from PyQt5.QtCore import QDir


class TreeView_Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        super(TreeView_Window, self).__init__()
        loadUi("GUI/tree_view_window.ui", self)
        self.btn_create_tree.clicked.connect(self.create_tree)
        self.treeModel = QFileSystemModel()
        self.treeView.doubleClicked.connect(self.getValue)

    def create_tree(self):
        path = r"C:\SomeFolder\AnotherFolder"
        password = "password"
        self.treeView.setModel(self.treeModel)
        self.treeModel.setRootPath(QDir.rootPath())
        self.treeView.setRootIndex(self.treeModel.index(path))
        self.treeView.setAnimated(False)
        self.treeView.setIndentation(20)
        [self.treeView.setColumnWidth(x, 200) for x in range(0, 4)]
        self.treeView.frameGeometry().width()
        self.treeView.setSortingEnabled(False)

        # Like so for example:
        for item, index in treeViewItems:  # Loop through the items
           decrypted_name = decryptFileName(item, password)  # Decrypt the name
           self.treeView.setItem(decrypted_name, index)  # update the item to the decrypted one
```

I tried: `self.treeModel.data(self.treeModel.index(0,0))` which only gives me the root 'C:'
Copying the folder and decrypting the copy is not an option due to the reduction in speed, etc.

Comment: The QFileSystemModel is a direct representation of the FS, so you cannot "set" items (as the result would making actual changes to the FS). How are file/folder names decrypted? Does the system use the absolute path, or a path relative to the root dir?

Comment: The encrypted name of the file is written to the file itself. For the foldernames I made file which saves the names. The names will be decrypted with a symmetrical key.  And the system uses the absolute path to the root dir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [QIdentityProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qidentityproxymodel.html) and override its `data()` function in order to return the decrypted name. For obvious reasons, you should always check if the given path actually corresponds to an encrypted file and return a proper value accordingly.

Note that, since the view will use a different model, you cannot use `setRootIndex()` with an index from the QFileSystemModel, as it would be invalid for the view, so you need to map the index to the proxy.

Also, if you need to implement this also for the other columns, you obviously need to check for them.

```py
class DecryptedModel(QIdentityProxyModel):
    def data(self, index, role=Qt.DisplayRole):
        if role == Qt.DisplayRole:
            if index.column() == 1: # file name
                path = self.sourceModel().filePath(
                    self.mapToSource(index))
                return decryptFileName(path, password)
            elif index.column() == 2: # size
                # etc.
        return super().data(index, role)

class TreeView_Window(QDialog):
    #...
    def create_tree(self):
        self.decryptModel = DecryptedModel()
        self.decryptModel.setSourceModel(self.treeModel)
        self.treeView.setModel(self.decryptModel)

        sourceRootIndex = self.treeModel.index(path)
        self.treeView.setRootIndex(
            self.decryptModel.mapFromSource(sourceRootIndex))
```

If you need to also provide renaming features, then you shall also check if the role is `EditRole` in `data()`, and also override `setData()` for the same role, by calling the `setData()` of the source model with the *encrypted* name.

Comment: I have two issues: setRootIndex no longer has an effect on the treeView (it indexes from the root C:) and is there a way of passing through not just only the decrypted filename but more than 1 value because I have multiple columns (name, type, size, date). KR

Comment: I encountered another issue: If I entry a encrypted path to the treeView, the data function in the DecryptedModel gets called over and over again (it like indexes through the path every secound), which causes massive lags to the GUI and the program itself.

Comment: @PascalVallaster What do you mean by "If I entry a encrypted path"?

Comment: So I enter a path to a folder that is encrypted. The data function gets called and decrypts all the encrypted names. As soon as this whole process is finished, the data function gets called again and does all the decryption stuff (...).

Comment: You "enter a path" **where**? Please, be more clear. As already written in my answer, if you want *write* access to the model, you also need to properly override the `setData()` method. Besides, without knowing how your [en/de]cryption system *actually* works, we cannot really help you **in any way**. You just provided a dummy function, we don't know what really happens under the hood.

Comment: I updated my question. I hope it is clearer now. KR

Comment: @PascalVallaster Sorry but questions must be self-contained, and cannot rely on external resources (especially temporary ones like repos/cloud); besides, the issue is with *this* answer, not the question. That said, `data()` is called *a lot* of times, even while just hovering the mouse on items, so it's understandable that your function gets called very often; if you want to avoid that, you'll probably need some form of caching, but that's not the scope of this post, so I'd suggest you to try to implement that and if you don't succeed then create a new question with a related [mre].

Comment: The thing is, I am (currently) not allowed to create any questions. But thanks for the help anyway, KR.

Comment: @PascalVallaster Then, be patient. I know it can be annoying, but those measures are to prevent people to ask lots of questions (some people don't take their time to *consider* what they're asking, they just ask lots of questions because they're too lazy to do anything on their own). As said, those multiple calls are probably expected (unless you did something wrong), so take some benefit from it: try to understand what happens and why. Remember that this is not a help desk, we don't provide fast answers, but we do try to provide *good* ones. Which may take some weeks, months, or even *years*.